# R subsetting by date range

Tags: r, date, range, subset

seems simple enough and I've been through all similar questions and applied them all... I'm either getting nothing or everything...

Trying to took at water temperatures (WTEMP) for specific date range(SAMPLE_DATE) 2007-06-01 to 2007-09-30   from (allconmon)

here is my code so far...

```
bydate<-subset(allconmon, allconmon$SAMPLE_DATE > as.Date("2007-06-01") & allconmon$SAMPLE_DATE < as.Date("2007-09-30"))
```

Ive also tried this but get errors

```
bydate2<- as.xts(allconmon$WTEMP,order.by=allconmon$SAMPLE_DATE)

 bydate2['2007-06-01/2007-09-30']

Error in xts(x, order.by = order.by, frequency = frequency, .CLASS = "double",  : 
  order.by requires an appropriate time-based object
```

not sure what I'm doing wrong here... seems to work for other people

Comment: You didn't provide a sample of `allconmon`, but my guess is that `SAMPLE_DATE` isn't a `Date` object.

Answer (score 0):

I will highly recommend you using `zoo` package in R while dealing with time series data.

The operation you mentioned is actually a `window` function in `zoo`. 
Here is the example from `?window`:

```
Examples

window(presidents, 1960, c(1969,4)) # values in the 1960's
window(presidents, deltat = 1)  # All Qtr1s
window(presidents, start = c(1945,3), deltat = 1)  # All Qtr3s
window(presidents, 1944, c(1979,2), extend = TRUE)

pres <- window(presidents, 1945, c(1949,4)) # values in the 1940's
window(pres, 1945.25, 1945.50) <- c(60, 70)
window(pres, 1944, 1944.75) <- 0 # will generate a warning
window(pres, c(1945,4), c(1949,4), frequency = 1) <- 85:89
pres
```

Here is [a list of papers](http://datafireball.com/2013/11/13/a-few-awesome-readings-from-jss/) from JSS demonstrating the usage of the `zoo` package also reshape your data which I found very inspiring.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!  on multiple levels...   first off I didn't notice that R did something funky with my sample date label when I uploaded from text file... probably my fault...

here is a small sample of the data set.   its 5,573,301 observations of 30 variables

notice the funky symbol in front of sample date.... not sure why R did that...

```
 ï..SAMPLE_DATE SampleTime STATION SONDE Layer TOTAL_DEPTH TOTAL_DEPTH_A BATT BATT_A     WTEMP WTEMP_A SPCOND SPCOND_A SALINITY SALINITY_A DO_SAT DO_SAT_A
```

however what I did....  (i changed the name to x as allconmon was a bit excessive)

```
x <- read.csv(file = "C:/Users/Desktop/cmon2001-08.txt",quote = "",header = TRUE,sep = "\t", na.strings = c("","NULL"))

library(chron)

x$month <- months(as.Date(x$ï..SAMPLE_DATE, "%Y-%m-%d"))

x$year <- substr(as.character(x$ï..SAMPLE_DATE), 1, 4)

 y <- x[x$month == 'June' | x$month == 'July' | x$month == 'August' | x$month == 'September' ,]
```

so now I was able to subset all my data by those 4 months and then later by year, station, and water temp....